# Extract lines in file to a new file

Tags: python-3.x

have a number of .txt files with data which i need to extract to other files while keeping original files intact.
The files contain lines that start with [A] or [B] (including the brackets). I need to be able to open original txt files and if lines = [A] extract all of these entries in file and save to another file as .txt.A and same with lines = [B] to file as .txt.B. 
Is this easy enough to do as cant get working as thought

```
selectPattern  = r"^[A]$"                          
for files in text_file:
    with open(files) as infiles:
        with open(files) as outfiles:                  
            lines = infiles.readlines()
            for line in lines:   
                if line.startswith(selectPattern):
                    outfiles +'.A'.write(lines)
```

Sample of Data in one of the files

```
#
# Instruction File
#
[-] Created 
[-]
[A]         12  15  16
[A]         23  21  12
[A]         31  21  23
[B]         45  54  23
[A]         32  32  31  
[B]         21  24  28
[B]         32  45  31
[B]         43  31  12
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: it doesnt write any output, no filename.txt.A file created

Comment: The code provided is incomplete, and you can provide a sample file.

Comment: I wasnt sure how to proceed with it, its extracted from larger python file. Sample file added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `selectPattern  = r"^[A]$"` to `selectPattern  = r"[A]"`. Then it can match the lines that begins with `[A]`.

The `startswith()` function *don't work with regex pattern*, it works with a literal string.

```
for files in text_file:
    with open(files) as infiles:
        with open(files+'.A', 'w') as outfiles:   # Modified                  
            lines = infiles.readlines()
            for line in lines:   
                if line.startswith(selectPattern):
                    outfiles.write(line)         # Modified
```

Comment: Ok thanks, changed however when run the he line outfiles +'.A'.write(lines) returns the following error - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: The filename of `outfiles` you read should contains the suffix `.A`. For example, `a.txt.A`. Then you read `a.txt.A`. After you read the file `a.txt.A`, then you can write the lines into the file with `outfiles.write(lines)`. @gcmtb

Comment: Thanks again @zhenguoli however getting TypeError: must be str, not list which i assume is due to defining the text_files directory as text_files = os.listdir("/testing/folder/text_files/")

Comment: Sorry ignore that i just realised i made a typo and put lines instead of line in the outfile.write(line). Thanks again @zhenguoli